# Create instance of a class that has a dependency without Constructor Injection or ServiceLocator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a wrapper class SessionData registered with Autofac that has IHttpContextAccessor injected in its constructor; Then I have a Parser class used to replace tokens in a string with values from varying sources, the user can instantiate an instance of the Parser class anywhere in the code, but one of the IAccessor's used by the Parser needs an instance of SessionData. The legacy version of this code used the ServiceLocator pattern; I'm trying to avoid that at all costs, I also don't want to use constructor injection because I don't want the constructors to become unmanageable; can anyone give me some direction?

// please excuse errors in the pseudo code that follows

```
// wrapper class to access values stored in Session
public class SessionData {
  public SessionData(IHttpConextAccessor) {...}
}

// class used to replace tokens in strings throughout the application
public class Parser {
  public Parser() {...}
  public string Parse(string value) {
    ...
    foreach(var token in GetTokens(value)) {
      if(token.type == "session") {
        var accessor = new SessionAccessor();
        token.value = accessor.GetValue(token.key)
        // replace tokens in value
      }
      ...
      // 20 different types of accessors
    }
  }
}

// interface for all Accessors
public interface IAccessor { 
  string GetValue(string key);  
}

// Accessor to get values from Session
public class SessionAccessor {
  SessionData _sessionData;
  public SessionAccessor(SessionData sessionData) {
    _sessionData = sessionData;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not really explaining the problem well, but it sounds like you just need to Inject a session accessor

Comment: How do I inject the SessionAccessor while allowing the user to do var parser = new Parser();

Comment: Why are you allowing them to do new parser, the parser should be injected as well

Comment: I’m trying to avoid having 26 parameter constrctors all over the application. Constructor Injection is great, but it gets out of control quickly.

Comment: You shouldn't have 26 parameters, you should group the parameters that relate to eachother together into another class and inject the group as a parameter into that class

Comment: e.g if a service requires a parser, and a session accessor and a db context, create a dto service options and inject those 3 things into it. and then only inject the service option dto in your service

Comment: Most of the use cases I have aren’t really groupable, I grouped ones that make sense, but in this case I need access in all different areas of the framework and not ever being able to use the Parser without passing it through every other dependency that may at some point need it feels overly bloated. Is there really no other acceptable way to accomplish this without Constructor Injection?

Comment: Well that's the trade off, if you're using Dependency Injection you should be using it entirely throughout you're project.    Don't get me wrong it's okay to have dependencies, e.g if you're using a list.  When it come's to your parser, it requires access to the httpcontext,  it sound like there's an architecture issue, you probably should have a service which handles the parsing for you but I can't see the full picture here without seeing more code.

Comment: If you have 26 constructor parameters you are probably in severe violation of the single responsibility principal. But you can do property or method injection, not just constructor.

Comment: I think I’m looking for something along these lines; https://jeffreypalermo.com/2010/01/constructor-over-injection-smell-ndash-follow-up/